# Pandas ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer error when doing a 'Run All' but works fine when running the specific cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

When doing an execute all in Jupiter notebook with the following code I receive a `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` error. But when I run this specific cell a second time it works fine. Is there anything specific that could be causing the error while doing a Run All but will work when just running the specific cell.

```
# New birthdate calculations
    def calculate_age(born):
        born = datetime.strptime(born, "%m/%d/%Y").date()
        today = date.today()
        return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
    
    def generate_birthdate(age):   
        today = date.today() 
        if int(age) < 18:
            new_birthdate = str(random.randrange(1,12))+'/'+str(random.randrange(1,28))+'/'+str(random.randrange(today.year-18,today.year))
        else:
            new_birthdate = str(random.randrange(1,12))+'/'+str(random.randrange(1,28))+'/'+str(random.randrange(today.year-90,today.year-18))
        return new_birthdate
    
    filt = (df_good_ssn['BIRTHDATE'] == '--/--/----')
    df_good_ssn.loc[filt,'BIRTHDATE'] = '01/01/2000' # '--/--/----' is invalid. Asign any valid date for type casting. Will be overwriten by generate_birthdate
    
    df_good_ssn.loc[~filt,'AGE'] = df_good_ssn['BIRTHDATE'].apply(calculate_age)
    df_good_ssn.loc[~filt,'NEW_BIRTHDATE'] = df_good_ssn['AGE'].apply(generate_birthdate)
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9e2113163ab5> in <module>
     18 
     19 df_good_ssn.loc[~filt,'AGE'] = df_good_ssn['BIRTHDATE'].apply(calculate_age)
---> 20 df_good_ssn.loc[~filt,'NEW_BIRTHDATE'] = df_good_ssn['AGE'].apply(generate_birthdate)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-5-9e2113163ab5> in generate_birthdate(age)
      7 def generate_birthdate(age):
      8     today = date.today()
----> 9     if int(age) < 18:
     10         new_birthdate = str(random.randrange(1,12))+'/'+str(random.randrange(1,28))+'/'+str(random.randrange(today.year-18,today.year))
     11     else:

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Comment: What type does `age` variable has? Like checking `print(type(age))`

Comment: @alphamu `print(type(age))` returns `<class 'int'>`

Comment: For somehow trace back shows `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`. Possibly, you may run something like `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)` prior to calling both those `.apply` methods. Please let me know if that helps? Otherwise, more code or data shall be required

Comment: @alphamu `df_good_ssn.loc[:,'AGE'].fillna('18', inplace=True)` after `.apply(calculate_age)` corrected the issue. But it appears that the source of the issue is `filt = (df_good_ssn['BIRTHDATE'] == '--/--/----')
    df_good_ssn.loc[filt,'BIRTHDATE'] = '01/01/2000'`. Any date that is assigned 01/01/2000 causes calculate_age to return an age of `nan` . I will look into that more. Please feel free to add your comment as an answer and will mark it as answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would tried something like

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

or similar applied to the column in question. That would have ensured the column data has type `int` to work from that point.

As for your comment, if it is the case with `filt` predicate, I would dig into something like pattern matching with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

The latter may be cumbersome, however, this shall serve the purpose well.